# how i can configure Android in Titanium?

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am New Developer for Titanium. I had install Titanium Package for iPhone it work fine. But, my Problem is when i configure Android SDK with Titanium. It will create some problem and not work properly. 
    So, If any one have Idea regarding my this problem. Please Help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You haven't specified what error you had, but follow the instructions on their wiki: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Quick+Start#QuickStart-MobileSDKInstallationandConfiguration

Comment: Yes, i will do. after this install. When we run my code in iPhone it run properly. but not run for Android Platform

Comment: You have to post any error messages you get and maybe a bit of code to people try to help you... Its really hard to help without any details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u open your Titanium Application, with application one a Dashboard Window here many type of contain or Menu show,
Menu : 
1. Configure
2. Learn
3. Develop
4. Explore

You, click in Configure and check android status, if ur android install or update successfully than, rum proper, 
otherwise, u make install or update than work properly,